# How to add text under each list in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

````
    return Container(
      height: 90,
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _trader.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 70,
                  width: 70,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: ()=> print('Go to profile'),
                    child: Image.asset('image/profileIcon.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            ),
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Comment: please add some description

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
return Container(
    height: 90,
    child: Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _trader.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: ()=> print('Go to profile'),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: 70,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('image/profileIcon.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("YOU WANT THAT TEXT")
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    ),
  );
```